# Exploding a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this, where the codes column is currently strings.

| Station | Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2,5 |
| 2 | 2,3 |
| 3 | 1 |

I want to see the count of each code ordered by station. I have tried to use the explode function but the default behavior is to overwrite all strings with only one number as NaN.

| Station | Codes | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 3):

```
print(
    df.assign(Codes=df.Codes.str.split(","))
    .explode("Codes")
    .groupby(["Station", "Codes"], as_index=False)
    .size()
    .rename(columns={"size": "Count"})
)
```

Prints:

```
   Station Codes  Count
0        1     1      2
1        1     2      1
2        2     1      1
3        2     2      2
4        2     3      1
5        2     5      1
6        3     1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Codes'] = df['Codes'].str.split(',')
df.explode('Codes').groupby('Station')['Codes'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Comment: I have tried using this approach as well, but using .split(",") results in NaN values in the cells that only have one number (no comma)